# How to wrap oEmbed-embedded video in DIV tags inside the_content?

Tags: filters, oembed

I am making a Wordpress Theme for a website with video tutorials. I would like to put the video that is embedded in the content (with [oEmbed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds)) in a apart div.

**An example**

The full content (output from `the_content()`) is something like this:

```
<p><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/0000000" width="900" height="506" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></p>
<p>This is an Test of a tutorial. Bla bla bla</p>
```

And I would like to get this to:

```
<div id="video">
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/0000000" width="900" height="506" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="content">
<p>This is an Test of a tutorial. Bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to split it via a regex, but it became a mess.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`embed_oembed_html`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/media.php#L1183) filter runs before an oEmbed resource's HTML is outputted, so you could hook into this and wrap the output in a `div` as below. I can't think of a simple way of wrapping the other content.

```
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'my_embed_oembed_html', 99, 4);
function my_embed_oembed_html($html, $url, $attr, $post_id) {
  return '<div id="video">' . $html . '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are attempting to use oEmbed in your Wordpress theme template, try this:

```
<aside>
    <p>oEmbed video in template test</p>
    <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', "http://vimeo.com/41205967"); ?>
</aside>
```

This snippet will display a video from Vimeo.com directly in your theme, without having to create a post manually.

Comment: The video's are embedded in posts. That was the problem.